# apache atlas - hook hive - how to build apache-atlas-${project.version}-hive-hook.gz?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, apache-atlas

I want to hook Hive for importing metadata automatically in atlas that is installed standalone. Instruction on apache atlas website says "untar apache-atlas-${project.version}-hive-hook.tar.gz" and I can't find this file.

I'v tried to build apache-atlas-sources and I ran into DependencyResolutionException error in "Apache atlas UI" step. Is there a mvn command which build just apache-atlas-${project.version}-hive-hook.tar.gz so I can finish the instructions? or is there a solution to DependencyResolutionException problem?

Comment: I'd recommend asking the Apache Atlas dev mailing list.

Comment: I emailed them two weeks ago but received no answer

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Building Apache Atlas from source produces the binaries and all hooks in separate tar files inside the `distro/target/` folder.

As stated in the apache [atlas github page](https://github.com/apache/atlas), the hooks are built along with the atlas binaries during the atlas build process. I've copied the relevant README information, particularly number 3:

> ## Build Process
>
> 1. Get Atlas sources to your local directory, for example with following commands

```
$ cd <your-local-directory>    
$ git clone https://github.com/apache/atlas.git    
$ cd atlas

# Checkout the branch or tag you would like to build
#
# to checkout a branch
$ git checkout <branch>

# to checkout a tag
$ git checkout tags/<tag>
```

> 2. Execute the following commands to build Apache Atlas

```
$ export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms2g -Xmx2g"
$ mvn clean install
$ mvn clean package -Pdist
```

> 3. After above build commands successfully complete, you should see the following files

```
distro/target/apache-atlas-<version>-bin.tar.gz
distro/target/apache-atlas-<version>-hbase-hook.tar.gz
distro/target/apache-atlas-<version>-hive-hook.tar.gz
distro/target/apache-atlas-<version>-impala-hook.tar.gz
distro/target/apache-atlas-<version>-kafka-hook.tar.gz
distro/target/apache-atlas-<version>-server.tar.gz
distro/target/apache-atlas-<version>-sources.tar.gz
distro/target/apache-atlas-<version>-sqoop-hook.tar.gz
distro/target/apache-atlas-<version>-storm-hook.tar.gz
distro/target/apache-atlas-<version>-falcon-hook.tar.gz
```